# While loop python incorrect

Tags: python, loops

```
def rep(x):
  i = 9
  while i <= 0:
    print x
    i = i - 1

a = "Red"
print rep(a)
```

My code does not produce "Red" 9 times as expected. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: What _does_ it produce? Also, post code, not screenshots of code.

Comment: condition in while is always false, probably you want `i >= 0`

Comment: because i equals 9 and you check if i <= 0 so it never enters the loop

Comment: Also, idiomatic python is probably `for i in range(9)` instead of rolling your own counter.

Answer (score 1):

```
def rep(x):
    i = 9
   while i <= 0:
```

Notice that this loop will never run because the condition will never be true. If `i` starts at 9, how can it be less than or equal to zero?

Perhaps you want:

```
i = 9
while i > 0:
```

But instead, consider this more Pythonic form:

```
for i in range(10):
    print x
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I always gets confused with while loop.

Comment: It's not difficult at all. Just *read* the code you've written and step through it in your head, statement by statement.

Comment: A while loop will work till a certain condition is met. Right ?

Comment: No. It runs *while* the condition is true.

Comment: So a while loop is type of  recursive if function that keeps on checking the condition after excuting a task

Comment: @akulchhillar Nope, none of this is true. It's not recursive, not a function and it checks _before_ loop, not after.

Comment: It's not recursive at all. It's like an `if` statement that gets checked before every iteration of the loop.  You need a good introductory book on programming. Stack Overflow is not intended to teach programming fundamentals.